# Checking value in an array from another array

Tags: python, arrays

So I wanted to see if it was possible to find values of two array's that are equal to each other but I am unsure how to do that.
This is what I have so far:

```
unusedArray = ["AS", "2S", "3S", "4S", "5S", "6S", "7S", "8S", "9S", "10S", "JS", "QS", "KS", "AD", "2D", "3D", "4D", "5D", "6D", "7D", "8D", "9D", "10D", "JD", "QD", "KD", "AH", "2H", "3H", "4H", "5H", "6H", "7H", "8H", "9H", "10H", "JH", "QH", "KH", "AC", "2C", "3C", "4C", "5C", "6C", "7C", "8C", "9C", "10C", "JC", "QC", "KC"]
```

`value10 = ["10S", "10C", "10H", "10D"]`

```
x = 0

for value10 in unusedArray:
   print(x)
   x += 1
```

The printing of `x` is just to see how many times the for loop is running. Instead of the loop only running 4 times it runs 52(amount of values in the `unusedArray`)

Comment: Why would it run four times if there are 52 things in the list you are looping over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert your lists to `sets` and use `intersection()`

```
u = set(list_1).intersection(set(list_2))
print(u)
print(len(u))
```

Notice you can do this for more lists, e.g.

```
u = set(list_1).intersection(set(list_2), set(list_3))
print(u)
print(len(u))
```

Otherwise:

```
u = [x for x in list_1 if x in list_2]
print(u)
print(len(u))
```

Comment: That's an odd way to call things. `set` is a type, you would normally do `set(list_1).intersection(list_2)` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension:

```
unusedArray = ["AS", "2S", "3S", "4S", "5S", "6S", "7S", "8S", "9S", "10S", "JS", "QS", "KS", "AD", "2D", "3D", "4D", "5D", "6D", "7D", "8D", "9D", "10D", "JD", "QD", "KD", "AH", "2H", "3H", "4H", "5H", "6H", "7H", "8H", "9H", "10H", "JH", "QH", "KH", "AC", "2C", "3C", "4C", "5C", "6C", "7C", "8C", "9C", "10C", "JC", "QC", "KC"] 

value10 = ["10S", "10C", "10H", "10D"]
final_List = [i for i in unusedArray if i in value10]
```

Output:

```
['10S', '10D', '10H', '10C']
```